# Forcing https on the whole site but not on one folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Could anyone tell me how I can force https on my whole website but not on a single folder or url.
At the moment I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thatmysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thatmysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But if I add this second code in the root htaccess to remove https from the /thatsite.com/printing folder, I get a redirect loop because I am forcing on the code http to https and not https to http...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(printing)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(printing)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Do you know a way around this please? I have been looking all over the internet and cannot find a single good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these 2 rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/printing [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /printing [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am impressed, this works perfectly! Thank you , I have been looking everywhere for this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by placing this code in an .htaccess file the root folder of the directory that hosts the http site (e.g. public_html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/TheFolderYouCanAccessWithoutHttp/
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!